# TSQL Collect data from multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently started learning SQL and ran into this problem that i'm unable to find solution.
I'm trying to collect data from multiple databases and output it to single table.

Source select outputs data in two columns "acAcct" and "name of source db"

Target table has "acAcct" and column for each db.

Thing that i came up with:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SET  @command = 'IF ''[?]'' NOT IN (''[master]'', ''[model]'', ''[msdb]'', ''[tempdb]'')

 INSERT INTO _utility.dbo.konta (acAcct, ''?'')
 SELECT DISTINCT AC.acAcct
                ,AD.acName AS ''?''                 
                        from tHE_AcctTransItem as AC
                        LEFT JOIN vDE_SetAccount as AD 
                        ON AC.acAcct = AD.acAcct'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

I get this error for each DB:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'name of DB'.
```

I guess i'm missing something with parsing of variable at:

```
INSERT INTO _utility.dbo.konta (acAcct, ''?'')
```

Select works fine.

EDIT:

Ended up with this:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SET  @command = 'IF ''[?]'' NOT IN (''[master]'', ''[model]'', ''[msdb]'', ''[tempdb]'')

MERGE  _utility.dbo.konta AS target
 USING (SELECT DISTINCT AC.acAcct
                ,AD.acName AS [?]                   
                        from [?].dbo.tHE_AcctTransItem as AC
                        LEFT JOIN [?].dbo.vDE_SetAccount as AD 
                        ON AC.acAcct = AD.acAcct) as source
    ON (target.acAcct = source.acAcct)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.[?] = source.[?]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (acAcct, [?])
            VALUES (source.acAcct, [?]);
            '
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Original script filled only first column and errored out on others.

Comment: What is the name of the column you are trying to insert to in `_utility.dbo.konta`? Is it different for each DB? Do you really have enough databases, with new ones being added frequently enough to warrant having to use Dynamic SQL for this process?

Comment: best thing to is break it up. Does the select on its own work? Does the IF on its own work?

Comment: There is around 30 databases and names of databases match column names in '_utility.dbo.konta'.

Comment: Everything except INSERT works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source database name is a column then it should not be enclosed in single quotes. Square brackets would be safer.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SET  @command = 'IF ''[?]'' NOT IN (''[master]'', ''[model]'', ''[msdb]'', ''[tempdb]'')

 INSERT INTO _utility.dbo.konta (acAcct, [?])
 SELECT DISTINCT AC.acAcct
        ,AD.acName AS [?]                 
            from tHE_AcctTransItem as AC
            LEFT JOIN vDE_SetAccount as AD 
            ON AC.acAcct = AD.acAcct'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```